# Como enviar uma pagina HTML no corpo de um email com PHP ?

Tags: php

Como enviar uma pagina HTML no corpo de um email com PHP ? 
Esse html contém algumas classes bootstrap,como posso enviar essa pagina com os estilos do bootstrap , ou estilos css usando a função mail do PHP

Comment: Não tem como carregar Bootstrap em HTML de email. Emails em HTML devem ser o mais simples possível usando apenas tags HTML e alguns estilos (os que funcionam. Alguns são ignorados pelos clientes de email) CSS inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando as opções do `header` do email:

```
$headers='Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"';
```

Você cria uma pagina `html` com `css` para os emails.

> [Aqui tem uma questão do SO inglês sobre isso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566182/complete-mail-header)
>
> [E aqui um artigo da CSS-TRICKS sobre o assunto](https://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/)